# return local variable as parameter

Tags: java, reference

return local variable as parameter

```
public String savedData(String Data, String m, String r, String s){
        String data = "asdfasdf";

        return Data;

    }
```

I want to return the local variable, data.. I put data.this = data, it won't work.. hmm what's wrong here?

Comment: You are returning `Data`, not `data`.

Comment: The terminologies you've used in your question are misleading. Rephrase you question. returning a parameter is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can't return a value in a parameter. `String` is *immutable* and you can only change the reference. You can't change the object passed in.

You *can* do this:

```
class StringHolder {
   public String value;
}

StringHolder s = new StringHolder;
s.value = "x";

savedData(s);
```

and have `savedData` change the object passed thus:

```
public String savedData(StringHolder data,....) {
   data.value = "new x";
```

I would really do this though (without being explicit). It's not particularly idiomatic and perhaps a little unexpected. I think you're much better off returning new objects through `return`. It's a good practice to follow - side effects make life complex in terms of debugging etc. and make multi-threading more problematic (since you have state changing under you)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String savedData(String Data, String m, String r, String s){
    String data = "asdfasdf";


    return data; // returning data not Data.

}
```

are you talking about above scenario ???.

Comment: I want to pass tring data = "asdfasdf"; possible?